# Reconstruct a variety from the category of locally free sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

We know that the category of the (quasi-)coherent sheaves on a smooth projective variety $X$ determine the variety (aka. Gabriel–Rosenberg reconstruction theorem) and the derived category of coherent sheaves on a smooth projective variety $X$ with $\omega_X$ ample or anti-ample determine the variety (aka. Bondal–Orlov reconstruction theorem).

Do we have any known results about whether the category of algebraic vector bundles (or locally free sheaves) $\mathbf{Vect}_a(X)$ can determine a variety?
$$\mathbf{Vect}_a(X)\cong \mathbf{Vect}_a(Y)\implies X\cong Y$$
Does it work when the equivalence is between categories, $k$-linear categories or a $k$-linear tensor categories?

Edit: refer to Martin Brandenburg in the comment, the affine case is algebraic and one can show it by corresponding results in algebra.

Comment: It will make a lot of difference whether you regard $\text{Vect}_a(X)$ as just a category, or a $\mathbb{C}$-linear category, or a $\mathbb{C}$-linear tensor category, so you should specify that.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, just edited.

Comment: First of all, Rosenberg's reconstruction theorem holds for all quasi-separated schemes (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.5978).

Comment: Of course you want to consider schemes with the resolution property, which means there are enough locally free sheaves. Projective schemes have this property, though. But the main problem here is that exact sequences in $\mathbf{Vect}(X)$ can be "weird", by which I mean that they don't have to be exact in $\mathbf{Qcoh}(X)$. For example, $2 : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is an epimorphism in the category of all locally free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, in fact all torsionfree $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, but of course not in the category of all $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. This already nukes many "obvious proofs".

Comment: The affine case is easy since a commutative ring R is not just (this is well-known) isomorphic to the center of the category of R-modules, but - with the same proof - also of the category of finitely generated projective R-modules. (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/center)

Comment: Some unfinished thoughts: Let $X$ be a scheme with $\mathbf{Vect}(X) \simeq \mathbf{Vect}(\mathbb{P}^n)$ as $k$-linear *tensor categories*. There is an invertible object $\mathcal{L} \in \mathbf{Vect}(X)$ and morphisms $s_0,\dotsc,s_n : \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{L}$ which correspond to $\mathcal{O}(1)$ and $t_0,\dotsc,t_n$ under the equivalence. Clearly $(s_0,\dotsc,s_n) : \mathcal{O}_X^n \to \mathcal{L}$ is an epi in $\mathbf{Vect}(X)$, but in order to construct $f : X \to \mathbb{P}^n$ with the universal property of $\mathbb{P}^n$, we need that it is an epi in $\mathbf{Qcoh}(X)$. Unclear!

Comment: Can someone please explain why the following isn't a counter-example? Take $R$ a PID. Then any finitely generated locally free $R$ module is free. So it seems that the category of locally free $R$ modules contains very little information in this case.

Comment: @DanielLoughran The set of isomorphism classes of objects does not remember much indeed, but the data of the category (which includes all morphisms between modules) does recover $R$: in the PID example you can recover $R$ as the endomorphisms of the only non-zero (i.e. non-initial) object that is not a coproduct of two non-zero objects.

Comment: Your post ends mid-sentence:  "In particular, we are interested in".

Comment: @DanielLoughran *A category is more than just its objects*

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand\Vect{\mathit{Vect}}\newcommand\Hom{\mathit{Hom}}$At least the birational tyie of a smooth projective variety can be recovered from the monoidal category of vector bundles on it. (the previous version of this answer claimed that the isomorphism class can be recovered but now I don't think that the original argument works)

For any line bundle $L$ on $X$ there is a dominant rational map from $X$ to $R(X,L):=\operatorname{Proj}\bigoplus H^0(X,L^n) $ which is an isomorphism if $L$ is very ample. In the monoidal category $\Vect(X)$ the invertible objects are precisely the line bundles, and the structure sheaf is the unit object, so given the category $\Vect(X)$ we can recover the collection of schemes $R(X,L)$ for all line bundles $L$ (because $H^0(X,L^n)=\Hom_{\Vect(X)}(O_X,L^{\otimes n})$), though we are not being told which of these arise from ample line bundles.

Let's discard all $R(X,L)$ that are not of finite type. Among the remaining ones all the $R(X,L)$s that have maximal dimension are birational to $X$, so the birational type of $X$ can be recovered from $(Vect(X),\otimes)$.

It is unclear to me right now how to recover $X$ itself: the issue is that an equivalence $(Vect(X),\otimes)\simeq (Vect(Y),\otimes)$ might a priori carry an ample line bundle on $X$ to a non-ample (though necessarily big) line bundle on another variety $Y$.

Comment: Unfortunately I lack the knowledge about algebraic geometry to understand this properly. But it seems that you overcome the problem that the property of being ample cannot be formulated within the category $\mathbf{Vect}(X)$ (again, the epimorphism issue!) by finding other conditions on the associated graded ring?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Maybe it is helpful to say that for your example of a variety $X$ with $Vect(X)=Vect(\mathbb{P}^n)$ what I'm suggesting comes down to simply turning your attempted argument around. Let's choose a very ample line bundle $L$ on $X$, it is carried to some $O(k)$ under this equivalence. The graded rings corresponding to $L$ and to $O(k)$ are isomorphic so we necessarily have $k>0$, and this proves that $X\simeq \mathbb{P}^n$ because $O(k)$ is very ample.

Comment: Why is X isomorphic to P^n here? Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg If $L$ is an ample line bundle on a projective variety $X$ then $X$ is isomorphic to $Proj \oplus H^0(X,L^n)$, see e.g. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01Q1 Hence if we are able to prove that an equivalence $Vect(X)\simeq Vect(Y)$ carries an ample line bundle $L$ on $X$ to an ample line bundle $M$ on $Y$ then $X\simeq Proj \oplus H^0(X,L^n)\simeq Proj \oplus H^0(Y,M^n)\simeq Y$. This is the situation in this example because an ample line bundle on $X$ is necessarily carried to an ample line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: Though I realized that my general argument is not quite correct: I was too hasty to claim that we can figure out which of the briationallly equivalent varieties $R(X,L)$ is $X$ itself, I edited the answer accordingly, so the original question is still open.

Comment: Oh, I see. Actually my gut feeling is that the answer is No. Already for $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Sorry which exactly statement you feel is false? I think it is true that if $Vect(X)\simeq Vect(\mathbb{P^n})$ then $X\simeq\mathbb{P^n}$ as sketched in my previous comments. This should more generally work for any variety with Neron-Sever rank 1 in place of $\mathbb{P}^n$.